# How do I databind a multibinding result to a DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

How do I assign the result of a MultiBinding to a DependencyProperty ?

Specifically, I want the "Details" DependencyProperty to be bound to DetailsEditor.Text.

**UserControl:**

```
<TextBox x:Name="DetailsEditor">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FilesToInstructionsConverter}" ConverterParameter=".dll|.exe|.config" 
                      UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
            <Binding ElementName="UserControl" Path="SourceDirectory"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
            <Binding ElementName="UserControl" Path="DestinationDirectory" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

**UserControl's Code-behind:**

```
public string Details
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DetailsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DetailsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DetailsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Details", typeof(string), typeof(DirectivesControl), null);
```

Comment: But where do I put ElementName=UserControl" Path=Details as a MultiBinding attribute?

Comment: SourceDirectory and DestinationDirectory are properties of the same UserControl?

Comment: Yes. The values from each property determines th Details property via the converter.

Comment: It might be easier to update these properties in their respective change callbacks. When Details changes, update SourceDirectory and DestinationDirectory. When the latter change, update Details.